# cygwin bash.rc to run two separate programs

Tags: bash, cygwin

I'm trying to run Python and Julia from the Cygwin command line, but I've installed Python and Julia to two separate directories. I can run Python from Cygwin with

`$ python testfile.py`

because I added `export PATH=/cygdrive/c/anaconda2:$PATH` to `bash.rc` so that I can run Python. However, my Julia installation sits in a different directory. Can I add something like `export PATH2=/cygdrive/c/Julia-0.5.1/bin:$PATH2` to run Julia files from command line with

`$ julia testfile.jl`

or what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not add both paths in the bash.rc?

```
export PATH=/cygdrive/c/anaconda2:/cygdrive/c/Julia-0.5.1/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Worked great -- thank you! One follow up (I'm new to bash/cygwin) question: how does the bash.rc file know which to use in these cases? As in could you explain what is actually going on?

Comment: The bash.rc file does not "know" anything about PATH. With the export, you are [re]defining the PATH environment variable with items that did not already exist in the PATH, and appending the original PATH. When a command is entered in a command shell or a system call is made by a program to execute a program, **the system first searches the current working directory** and **then searches the PATH, examining each directory from left to right**, seeking an executable filename that matches the given command. ... You can view the current PATH value by typing `echo $PATH` in the cygwin terminal.